# GreenDao helper class

Tags: android, greendao

I'm creating a class called DBHelper to make easier to use dao inside my app but i dont know how to do a simple select they keep giving that "Getting starting" link but a I dont understand nothing, any help modifing these codes from the class to do a simple select?

"select * from SEGUIMENTO"

```
public class DBHelper {

    static DaoSession daoSession;
    static DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper daoMasterDevOpenHelper;
    static DaoMaster daoMaster;
    static SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Context context;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        setupDatabase();
    }

    public void setupDatabase()
    {
        daoMasterDevOpenHelper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context,"guest-db",null);
        sqLiteDatabase = daoMasterDevOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        daoMaster = new DaoMaster(sqLiteDatabase);
        daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use the GreenDao [QueryBuilder](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/) to do `SELECT`s. But this would be overkill for your example.

In your case, since you are simply dumping out the entire table, you can just use the [loadAll()](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/de/greenrobot/dao/AbstractDao.html#loadAll()) method of your entity's Dao class. This illustrates why using DAO is so powerful.

For example, if your entity is named "Seguimento", you can call: `daoSession.getSeguimentoDao().loadAll()`, which will return a `List<Seguimento>`.